# Porque existe uma medalha de critico?

Tags: debate, medalhas

Bom dia, estou aqui por um motivo especifico que é uma das medalhas dada aos usuários, para se ganhar esse medalha você precisa dar um voto negativo na pergunta de alguém, eu não acho que essa medalha seja justa, pois pessoas acabam entrando em perguntas aleatórias e dão votos negativos por uma medalha, o site já tem problemas com votos negativos desnecessários, em minha opinião essa medalha deveria ser editada para algo como,
um voto negativo e um comentário construtivo por exemplo, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Cuidado com as afirmações que você está fazendo nessa pergunta. *"pois existem usuários que procuram aumentar sua reputação de um jeito mais fácil"*, com base em que você está afirmando isso? Não existe outro jeito de ganhar reputação no site, a não ser com boas perguntas e respostas. E o intuito da medalha é mostrar todos os recursos do site, inclusive o negativo, que é um bom recurso, quando usado corretamente. Não justifica a remoção da medalha se o usuário faz mau uso do recurso.

Comment: Pergunta editada de acordo com a sua observação obrigado.

Comment: eu concordo com você que o voto negativo é um bom recurso que ajuda os usuários a perceberem que você está fazendo algo de errado, mas eu também acho que esse voto deveria ser justificado como uma ajuda a os usuários recentes  para eles conseguirem avançar no site, mas acontece muito pelo contrário , muita pessoas só deixam seu voto negativo e vazam, oque acaba gerando uma frustração a pessoa que fez a pergunta.

Comment: Isso já foi bastante discutivo aqui no meta e no metão e não existe consenso, uma vez que é opcional a cada usuário isso(obrigar jamais será o melhor caminho). Veja [essa pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4948/n%C3%A3o-entendo-votos-negativos-e-voc%C3%AA) por exemplo.

Comment: Neste caso eu concordo com o @Nikk17016. Lembrando que a medalha é apenas para o primeiro voto, obrigar a pessoa deixar comentário para ganhar essa medalha pode ser uma forma de "ensinar" a deixarem um comentário. Claro, o user pode votar sem deixar comentário, como já foi discutido inúmeras vezes, mas obrigando a deixar para ganhar uma medalha única, pode ser um "coisa boa".

Comment: Concordo com vocês, obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: Pense no downvote em outros casos(extremos), como spam ou trollagem essas publicações sempre levam vários negativos, justo né ;) ?

Comment: No caso de zoeiras e trollagens nós teriamos como sinalizar as perguntas paras os adms.

Comment: Se obrigar colocar um comentário para dar a medalha pode funcionar. É claro que ele pode comentar apenas com um "se fudeu" e ganhar a medalha :D Fora isto, precisaria de uma reestruturação mais profunda em todo mecanismo.

Comment: Medalhas do Stack Exchange são como troféus da PSN/conquistas da Live/Achievements do Steam: pessoas que colecionam de verdade essas coisas podem melhorar consideravelmente sua qualidade de vida com a ajuda de um psicólogo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O objetivo de toda medalha é incentivar um comportamento, o crítico é uma demonstração que o usuário contribuiu com respostas, perguntas ou edições e chegou aos 125 pontos, quando é oferecido o [privilégio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) do downvote.

O crítico é aquele individuo (talvez ele até seja um especialista naquele assunto) que tem a capacidade de avaliar uma situação ou um objeto e fazer observações sobre determinados pontos que podem ser positivos ou negativos. Pense no crítico como aquele profissional que faz resenhas de livros, filmes etc e não naquela pessoa só reclama.

No site o negativo funciona como classificador das publicações, aquelas com vários negativos indicam que existe algo errado na solução/abordagem.

Recomenda-se que antes de negativar algo, avalie a situação, peça esclarecimentos ou indique o erro na resposta e espere um tempo ex: 4-5 horas para o outro usuário corrigir os problemas ou descrever melhor a sitaução, caso nada tenha mudado o downvote é opção.

Answer (score 3):

Uma coisa que eu tenho notado em todos os stacks: as pessoas com as reputações mais altas são apaixonadas pelo assunto do stack e vêem medalhas e reputações como coisas secundárias.

Eu mesmo tinha até esquecido que existe esse sistema de medalhas até você vir aqui e nos lembrar disso.

As "premiações" dadas aos usuários são mais um agrado bem-humorado do que um jogo. Até porque a sua quantidade de medalhas:

- Não tem peso no seu currículo;
- Não dá permissões extras no site, ao contrário da reputação;
- Não dá peso a argumento;
- Não aumenta sua auto-estima. Pelo contrário, se você liga pra isso, só dá é ansiedade;
- etc., etc.

Ou seja, foque na qualidade dos seus posts e no seu comportamento na rede, e não nos enfeites do seu perfil para os quais ninguém liga.